# Qu'est-ce que c'est un staffier?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, histoire, littérature, italien

Dans les mémoires de Casanova, Tome I, Chapitre IX, page 263, se trouve la phrase suivante:

> Ensuite, suivi d'un staffier, il m'accompagna au troisième à l'appartement qui m'était destiné, et qui était fort proprement meublé.

Selon le contexte, il me semble clair qu'un staffier est une sorte de personnel. Comparez staff en anglais. Mais dans les dictionnaires courants je ne trouve pas ce mot. Ce n'est ni français, ni italien. (Les mots italiens sont assez répandus dans l'œuvre de Casanova.)

Est-ce que vous avez une solution? Peut-être quelqu'un peut insérer ce mot dans le Wiktionnaire. Ça serait un grand service.

Contexte: Il s'agit ici de l'introduction de Casanova dans un domicile ecclésiastique. On le mène dans sa nouvelle chambre. Il est le maître d'hôtel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce « staffier » est à tout le moins un *domestique*, tel qu'y réfère l'auteur :

> Après cette courte instruction et m'avoir assuré que je pouvais
> compter sur son amitié, il me fit conduire chez le maître d'hôtel, qui
> me fit signer mon nom au bas d'une feuille d'un grand livre remplie
> d'autres noms, après quoi il me compta soixante écus romains pour
> trois mois d'appointemens payés d'avance. En suite, suivi d'un
> **staffier**, il m'accompagna au troisième à l'appartement qui m'était
> destiné, et qui était fort proprement meublé. En sortant le
> **domestique** me remit la clef en me disant qu'il viendrait tous les matins pour me servir, et le maître d'hôtel m'accompagna jusqu'à la
> porte pour me faire connaître au portier. [...]
>
> [ [*Mémoires de J. Casanova de Seingalt, écrits par lui-même*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k314854/f286.item), [Giacomo Casanova](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova), page 263 (je souligne) ]

C'est en fait un [*esta(f)fier*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/estafier), tel qu'en témoigne il me semble le [manuscrit](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b6000810t/f272.item.zoom#) autographe [acquis](https://gallica.bnf.fr/conseils/content/giacomo-casanova) par BnF :

[image]

Un *estafier* est soit historiquement un « domestique armé, en livrée, chargé de porter le manteau et les armes de son maître, de lui tenir l'étrier » ou, en Italie, un « [laquais](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laquais) en [livrée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/livr%C3%A9e) au service d'un cardinal, d'un pape ou d'un grand seigneur » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/estafier)), donc un valet en tenue de domestique et dans le texte il semble s'agir d'un simple domestique rattaché au maître d’hôtel. Il s'agit en effet d'un emprunt au *staffiere* italien ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/estafier)) et on a déjà eu la graphie *staffier* anciennement (1476) avant d'avoir *estaffier* (1549, chez Rabelais) ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/estafier)) puis peu de temps après *estafier*, tel qu'on l'orthographie [aujourd'hui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/estafier).

Answer (score 0):

Ça vient de l'italien staffiere. Il faut ajouter ce mot dans le Wiktionnaire un jour. Ça signifie un valet.

Comment: Est-ce que vous avez des indication sur l'usage de ce mot ? Est-il tombé en désuétude ? Pour ma part, c'est le première fois que je lis ce mot.

Comment: J'imagine que c'est un italianisme de Casanova car il est vénitien. Peut-être c'est son propre usage, un néologisme inventé pour son livre (un peu comme renarderie), peut-être ça paraît dans autres sources aussi.

Comment: Remarquons qu'une Renault estafette a une étymologie apparentée.

Comment: Oui, et avant d'être une camionnette, une estafette est un soldat à cheval qui porte des dépêches.